# CATransform3DMakeRotation causes UIimage rotation along with UIimageview

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, core-animation

I am facing a problem with `UIImageView` rotation.

I need to rotate the `UIImageView` horizontally with animation like ads.

To do this I am using the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay:0.0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
        animations:^{
             if (baddview) {
                 baddview = FALSE;
                 adimageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 1, 0);                          
             } else {
                 baddview = TRUE;
                 adimageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0);                          
             }
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         }
];
```

The imageview is rotating as I need it but the image in the image view is appearing reversed, like after a 180 degrees rotation ([you can see the image here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/89x2m)).

How can I animate the `UIImageView` rotation without rotating the `UIImage`?

Comment: hi what u want to perform... ? baddview is what...?

Comment: do you want to rotate image or not...

Comment: no,i want image as original and need just  animation of Uiimageview

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is making 2 `UIImageView`s, and animating them. What you would have to do is:

1. Before the animation block, create the new `UIImageView` and place it behind the current `UIImageView`, but make sure that it has a rotation of 180.
2. Make two animation blocks, one that rotates the first view **90** degrees at **half** (ie 0.5 sec) the duration, and the other block animates the view behind to `CATransform3DIdentity` at **full** duration (ie 1.0 sec).

I will add some code if needed.

Or alternatively, set the `isDoubleSided` property of `CALayer` to `NO`. Then, rotate both views 180 degrees. The top view will be hidden, since it is not double sided.

---

I just created a new single-view project, and added a `UIButton` to perform the flip. Here is the rest of the code:

**Header File:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView* _imageView1;
    UIImageView* _imageView2;
}

- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Implementation file:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gaara1.png"];
    _imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    [_imageView1 setFrame:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - 300)/2, 100.f, 300, 75)];

    UIImage* image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gaara2.png"];
    _imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];
    [_imageView2 setFrame:CGRectMake((CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - 300)/2, 100.f, 300, 75)];
    // the second imageView is in the back
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView2];
    [self.view addSubview:_imageView1];

}

- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {
    [_imageView1.layer setDoubleSided:NO];
    [_imageView2.layer setDoubleSided:NO];

    [_imageView1.layer setZPosition:10.f];

    [_imageView1.layer setTransform:CATransform3DIdentity];
    [_imageView2.layer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         _imageView1.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
                         _imageView2.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

}

@end
```

The images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like your solution resolve my problem.But little bit confusion can you provide bit of sample code.

Comment: @maheshbabu I am cooking some code right now, please prepare the dishes.. Will post soon.

Comment: @maheshbabu Added the code! If it works out well, we always appreciate an accepted answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is likely to cause problems. UIView animations are for animating the properties of a UIView, not layers.

I expect problems if you try to manipulate layer transforms in a UIView animation block. You should limit yourself to changing view properties in a UIView animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     _imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     _imageView2.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

CAAnimation objects are for animating layers.

If you want to animate your view's layer transform, either do it directly (which will give you an implicit animation) or create a CABasicAnimation object to do more complex animations.

Comment: Naah, your code actually rotates the view in the xy plane, while the OP wants to rotate the view in the xyz space. Animating the layers is the only way.